# How do I access a date picker user selected value, from within a word document, to use in in the same document using VBA?

Tags: date, ms-word, datepicker

I need to add Excel style automatic date creation, based on a user input in Word.  After accessing development menu I can insert a date picker menu control from the dev menu.  This provides a simple and easy to enter date format.  I then wish to take the user selected value and add additional dates based on that date selection, increased by a number of days, and have these dates automatically appear into another area of the document.  I have not been successful in searching online.  Does anyone know of a solution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that, you'll need a ContentControlOnExit macro coded along the lines of:

```
Private Sub Document_ContentControlOnExit(ByVal CCtrl As ContentControl, Cancel As Boolean)
Dim DtVal As Date, Fmt As String
With CCtrl
  If .Type = wdContentControlDate Then
    Fmt = .DateDisplayFormat
    .DateDisplayFormat = "MMM-DD-YYYY"
    DtVal = CDate(.Range.Text)
    .DateDisplayFormat = Fmt
    With ActiveDocument
      .SelectContentControlsByTitle("Date1")(1).Range.Text = Format(DtVal + 5, "MMM D, YYYY")
      .SelectContentControlsByTitle("Date2")(1).Range.Text = Format(DtVal + 21, "MMM D, YYYY")
      .SelectContentControlsByTitle("Date3")(1).Range.Text = Format(DtVal + 90, "MMM D, YYYY")
    End With
  End If
End With
End Sub
```

and inserted into the 'ThisDocument' code module of the document or its template, where the output *text* content controls are titled Date1, Date2, Date3, etc.

Comment: Thank you for this response, I clearly have a long way to go, to understand this environment.  I will need to study VB on Word in far more detail.  

When I create this, I am prompted for a macro name.  This then creates and empty macro method below this code.  I still don't know how I translate my **Date Picker Content Control**'s user inputted value from what the user selects, into the VB macro.  Th options in the **Content Control Properties** allows for a _tag_ and a _Title_ to be defined.  How does this translate into the VB editor?

Comment: How are you 'creating' this? You should simply copy & paste the code from my answer into the 'ThisDocument' code module of the document or its template, using the VBA Editor - which you access via Alt-F11. As you can see from the above code - and as per the comments I included following it, the Titles (and tags) can be addressed directly by name, viz.: .SelectContentControlsByTitle("Date1"). If you have more date picker content controls and want to limit the macro's operation to a particular one, give it a title (e.g. 'MyTitle') and insert If .Title <> "MyTitle" Then Exit Sub after With CCtrl.